# How to convert following flatMap/map snippet to for-comprehension in Scala?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

What can be best (liner/call-back free, less boilerplate) form of for-comprehension of following code snippet in Scala?

```
val result = emailTakenFuture.flatMap { emailTaken =>
  if (emailTaken) {
    Future.successful(SignUpResult.EmailAlreadyTaken)
  } else {
    usernameTakenFuture.flatMap { usernameTaken =>
      if (usernameTaken) {
        Future.successful(SignUpResult.UsernameAlreadyTaken)
      } else {
        nextIdFuture.flatMap { userId =>
          storeUserFuture(userId).map(user => SignUpResult.Success(user))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only the part after the last `else` is really a good fit for a for-comprehension:

```
for {
  userId <- nextIdFuture
  user <- storeUserFuture(userId)
} yield SignUpResult.Success(user)
```

I'd just write a helper function for the rest:

```
def condFlatMap[T](future: Future[Boolean], ifTrue: T)(ifFalse: => Future[T]): Future[T] = 
  future.flatMap(x => if (x) Future.successful(ifTrue) else ifFalse)

val result = 
  condFlatMap(emailTakenFuture, SignUpResult.EmailAlreadyTaken) {
    condFlatMap(usernameTakenFuture, SignUpResult.UsernameAlreadyTaken) {
      for {
        userId <- nextIdFuture
        user <- storeUserFuture(userId)
      } yield SignUpResult.Success(user)
    }
  }
```

(not tested, but should be approximately correct)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider wrapping the intermediary results in Throwables. Then you can later recover on your future -- pattern matching for only those exceptions.

I included the "boilerplate" to make the example compilable:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.global

case class User()

def emailTakenFuture: Future[Boolean] = ???
def usernameTakenFuture: Future[Boolean] = ???
def nextIdFuture: Future[String] = ???
def storeUserFuture(userId: String): Future[User]
```

For brevity, I extended Throwable. You may want to wrap the signup results in custom exceptions, in order to not expose them together with the `SignupResult`type.

```scala
trait SignUpResult

case object SignUpResult {
  case object EmailAlreadyTaken extends Throwable with SignUpResult
  case object UsernameAlreadyTaken extends Throwable with SignUpResult
  case class Success(user: User) extends SignUpResult
}

val result: Future[SignUpResult] = {
  (for {
    emailTaken <- emailTakenFuture
    _ <- if (emailTaken) Future.failed(SignUpResult.EmailAlreadyTaken) else Future.successful(Unit)
    userNameTaken <- usernameTakenFuture
    _ <- if (userNameTaken) Future.failed(SignUpResult.UsernameAlreadyTaken) else Future.successful(Unit)
    userId <- nextIdFuture
    user <- storeUserFuture(userId)
  } yield SignUpResult.Success(user)).recoverWith {
    case (SignUpResult.EmailAlreadyTaken) => Future.successful(SignUpResult.EmailAlreadyTaken)
    case (SignUpResult.UsernameAlreadyTaken) => Future.successful(SignUpResult.UsernameAlreadyTaken)
  }
}
```

Comment: This implies that, for example, `EmailAlreadyTaken` is a failure, though it might be a valid response.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. That is why I suggested: "You may want to wrap the signup results in custom exceptions".

To my understanding, OP was asking for a call-back-free for-comprehension, which I gave an example for.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`EitherT`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html) refactoring

```
type SignupResult[A] = EitherT[Future, SignupError, A]
```

where `SignupError` is the following ADT:

```
sealed trait SignupError
case object EmailAlreadyTaken    extends SignupError
case object UsernameAlreadyTaken extends SignupError
case object UserIdError          extends SignupError
case object UserCreationError    extends SignupError
```

then given the following method signatures

```
def validateEmail(email: String): SignupResult[Unit] = ???
def validateUsername(username: String): SignupResult[Unit] = ???
def nextId(): SignupResult[String] = ???
def storeUser(userId: String): SignupResult[User] = ???
```

flow flattens to a clean for-comprehension

```
(for {
  _      <- validateEmail("picard@starfleet.org")
  _      <- validateUsername("picard")
  userId <- nextId()
  user   <- storeUser(userId)
} yield user).value
```

Here is a working [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/E5fLN7hES9O8viuQeY5Zdw)

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object EitherTExample extends App {
  sealed trait SignupError
  case object EmailAlreadyTaken extends SignupError
  case object UsernameAlreadyTaken extends SignupError
  case object UserIdError extends SignupError
  case object UserCreationError extends SignupError

  final case class User(id: String, username: String)

  type SignupResult[A] = EitherT[Future, SignupError, A]

  def validateEmail(email: String): SignupResult[Unit] = EitherT.rightT(())
  def validateUsername(username: String): SignupResult[Unit] = EitherT.leftT(UsernameAlreadyTaken)
  def nextId(): SignupResult[String] = EitherT.rightT("42424242")
  def storeUser(userId: String): SignupResult[User] = EitherT.rightT(User("42424242", "picard"))

  val result: Future[Either[SignupError, User]] =
    (for {
      _      <- validateEmail("picard@starfleet.org")
      _      <- validateUsername("picard")
      userId <- nextId()
      user   <- storeUser(userId)
    } yield user).value

  result.map(v => println(v))
}
```

which outputs

```
Left(UsernameAlreadyTaken)
```

Note how instead of `true`/`false` for validation purposes we have `Right`/`Left`.

Comment: This. EitherT as a transformer for short-circuiting while keeping typed validation errors (plus untyped Throwables for actually exceptional errors in the Future). Alternatively use something like ZIO so that you have typed errors built-in into the effect (less complexity and better type inference than monad transformers).